# How can I trigger a change in jquery when server variable changes value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have created a site where I now need to 
do a postback, perform some logic, change a specific bolean variable from it's default value false to true and when i come back to the view(aspx page) i want to trigger a change in my javascript code.

On the aspx page i present this bolean value but i can not catch the change in jquery.

I am using an updatepanel and an AsyncPostBackTrigger.

basicly i click the button do the postback and change the value

```
<asp:Button ID="Book" CssClass="ecommercebutton btn btn-primary " runat="server" Text="Book" OnClick="Book_Click" />
<div id="NeededVAriable" style="display: none"><%=Test.ToString().ToLower()%></div>
```

and in my jquery script:

```
 $("#NeededVAriable").live("change",function () {
            alert("i am here")
    })
```

My change function never gets hit...
How do i do this?

Thanks!

Comment: I think you can work with change on only some of the HTML controls Source:http://api.jquery.com/change/

Answer (score 1):

For div you have to detect change like this:

```
$("#NeededVAriable").on("DOMSubtreeModified",function(){
  alert('changed');
});
```

[**DEMO EXAMPLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/6Fx23/)

Comment: does not work... to be clear im not reloading the entire page, just the updatepanel.

And i do not change the content via script i change the bolean value on the server side

Comment: if its server side variable what are you trying to do with jquery??

Comment: When i do my postback i change the value on the variable from false to true IF it fullfilles certain criteria.

I want to catch this change with jquery, i want to know when the value changes from false to true and perform some script logic